# Table's row doesn't delete with js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have:

**in _table:**

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', project, remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Sure?' },
                    class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
```

**in projects_controller**

```
 def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy
  end
```

**in destroy.js.erb**

```
var element = document.getElementById("project_<%= @project.id %>");
alert("project_<%= @project.id %>"); <--- Here ID is right!
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Click on Delete button destroys project in DB, but table row stays in table. What could be the problem?

Below is generated html, target is `#project_21`:

```
<table id="project-table" class="table-striped">   <thead>   <tr>
    <th>Название проекта</th>
    <th>Описание проекта</th>
    <th></th>   </tr>   </thead>



  <tbody>

  <tr class="project" id="project_21">
      <td>мой</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-accept btn-xs" href="/projects/21/edit">Редактировать</a>
        <a data-confirm="Вы уверены?" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/projects/21">Удалить</a>
      </td>

</tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: can you paste your row html.

Comment: @JustinLicata updated

Comment: 1. Have you tried deleting your row through browser console? 
2. Are there any errors in browser js console after request?

Comment: @Phil yes, in console everything works fine. no errors. I have same code in another controller, and it works. Can't understand, what happen..

Comment: @nobilik I would try jquery if I were you.. The code above looks okay

Comment: @Phil Mystic! jquery works fine! But what the deal?)

Comment: @nobilik I would tell if I knew. I never use plain js as this, only jQuery, sorry. Glad to help, anyway :)

Comment: Your vanilla JS looks fine.